# AWS Lambda to create another Lambda using the function in codecommit

Tags: aws-lambda

I am trying to understand if we can create a LAMBDA function which when execute will create a new Lambda function (if it doesn't exists) or update with a new version if it was already existing. The new lambda function will be stored in Codecommit and therefore the invoking lambda function should be able to clone the codecommit repo and use that function cloned to create the new one. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it,

> CodeCommit (Trigger) --> Lambda (Trigger External Process to build and
>   zip it to S3) --> S3 (Create Trigger) --> Lambda(Update Lambda Code [Self or Other Lambda)

With CodeCommit you can also pass in parameters that can differentiate repository to trigger different build process.

Hope it helps.